# How do I define exchange(X) to make this theorem without error?

Tags: isabelle

I am learning to use Isabelle to prove certain theories, but I encountered a problem. I would like to know how can I define `exchange(X)` to ensure that the theorem presented in the code listing below can be stated without causing an error?

```
theorem exchange_wp2_1:
  "
  preOrder(T) =X @ preOrder(q) @ F(S) ∧ exchange(X) ∧ q ≠ null ⟹
    preOrder(T)=X @ (data q) @ preOrder(ltree q) @ F ([rtree q] @ S)
  "
```

Error:

> Type unification failed:Cash of types "_list" and "_tree" Type error
>   in application:incompatible operand type Operator:  exchange::??
>   'tree⇒bool Operator: X::?? 'b list

Comment: Having only my best intentions in mind, may I suggest you to read the following sections of the SO documentation: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example? I would also like to draw your attention to the features of the website for code formatting. Moreover, I would like to emphasize that it is very useful to ensure that the problem in your question can be reproduced. Without having your definitions of the constants that are used in the theorem, the statement of the theorem in the global context of Main does not cause any errors.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly the definitions of preOrder and exchange, but it seems that `preOrder` returns a list, whereas `exchange` expects a tree as input. So, in your expression, it is unclear what type `X` should have: is it a tree or a list?

```
preOrder(T) = X        (so X is list)
exchange X             (so X is a tree)
```

this is what the error message tells you.

Comment: I also didn't define the type of S in q and F(S) in preOrder(q), but Isabelle did not report an error. X is a list, how should I define this X?@René Thiemann